# How to manage ldap users/kerberos principals on Ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, user-management, kerberos

I've recently setup a small test network with an Ubuntu server and Ubuntu clients. People can login to a client machine using an account stored in LDAP (created using ldapadduser from the ldapscripts package).

The problem has arisen when it came to sharing home dirs from the server using NFS. The only secure way to do this in the environment which it is eventually going to be deployed is using Kerberos.

I can share home dirs using nfs and kerberos fine, however, this means that every ldap user also needs a kerberos principal creating. Is there a common way of managing such a system? I can't find any standard tools (GUI or CLI) for managing what I would have thought is a very common setup?

Perhaps I'm going about things the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked into FreeIPA yet? It is a Redhat project for fedora, but it does exactly what you are looking for. Can you use a Fedora server instead of a Ubuntu one? If so it will take care of stuff for you.

I setup an Ubuntu server and client setup here, I wish I had used FreeIPA instead. If you can configure Ubuntu desktops to work off a LDAP / Kerberos setup, you can do go against the FreeIPA stack as well, its just more work then using Fedora for both sides.